# русские буквы в bytes python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, кодировка

вчера, пытаясь создать простой socket сервер я столкнклся с не понятной мне проблемой: итак, я использую python3.8 и из программы написаной на c# получаю `bytes` в кодировке `utf-16` и хочу вернуть то клиенту тот же текст, что он прислал, но большими буквами:

```py
connection.send(data.upper())
#data - полученные из подуключения данные, connection - подключение полученное из  socket().accept()
```

НО `data` имеет тип `bytes` и назад пользователю приходят увеличенные английские буквы, и не измененные русские, то есть, если пользователь прислал `Привет my dear друг` то назад ему придет `Привет MY DEAR друг`, данная проблема решается переводом `bytes` в `str`вызовом `str.upper()` и переводом назад в `bytes`, но, что делать если я хочу использовать сразу bytes?

тем более, что я могу не знать в какой кодировке я получаю от пользователя данные, и следовательно не знать как правильно перевести данные в `str` и обратно?

P.S. python3.8, Windows 10 64bit

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сначала декодировать данные из байт в строку, тогда метод `upper()` будет понимать, что у вас буквы, а не просто какой-то набор байт. Перед отправкой обратно закодировать в байты.

```
connection.send(data.decode('utf-16').upper().encode('utf-16')
```

Почему не работает сразу с байтами? В разных кодировках региональные алфавиты (кириллица в данном случае) могут быть представлены совершенно по-разному, в наборе байт только для латинских символов можно хоть с какой-то уверенностью сказать что это буква. Поэтому `lower` и `upper` в байтах работает только для латиницы.